# Facebook API Like a Page with Auth Token

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I've got a Facebook oauth token and I'm trying to Like a page for a user who has given me permission to do so. Assuming 123456789 is the id of the Facebook page the user wants to Like, I post to this page and get the following error:

https://graph.facebook.com/123456789/likes?access_token=...

```
{
    "error":{
        "type":"OAuthException",
        "message":"(#3) Application does not have the capability to make this API call."
    }
}
```

This page of the Facebook documentation (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) says:

> You can comment on or like any object that has a /comments or /likes
>   connection by posting to https://graph.facebook.com/OBJECT_ID/comments
>   and https://graph.facebook.com/OBJECT_ID/likes, respectively

The user wants to Like a Facebook Page and the Page documentation (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/) shows that it does have a /likes connection, so it should be Like'able via the api... but it's not working. Any ideas?

Comment: I just realized my confusion. The Page documentation shows that the Page Object has a /likes FIELD but not a /likes CONNECTION. Dammit.

Comment: You can't submit a like action via the API. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Currently this is only possible with the old (and DEPRECATED) REST API. Using the method "pages.addFan". Though this method is not visible in Facebook's API Documentation. 
So I assume that this is also possible somehow with the new Graph API, because their Facebook mobile apps will need to move on to their new APIs soon, and they make use of the Page Like function.

What's really weird, is that their brand new iPad app, is based on the old REST API! Interesting...

Comment: pages.addFan also gives the same error as above. perhaps its limited to allowed Apps or FB apps